showModalDialog vs showModelessDialog
The documentation on showModalDialog vs showModelessDialog says this:

In almost all cases, a modal dialog or sidebar is a better choice than a modeless dialog.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)

Why is it a better choice?
This is a sub-question from my overall aim is of creating a Google Apps Script function to download a zip file directly to my local device.
This answer to a related question provides two solutions. The first from Tanaike uses showModalDialog and the second from TheMaster uses showModelessDialog.
My question arises from a desire to understand their answers better.

If I were writing the comment I would have switched the positions of the words modal and modeless.  I think it's a matter of personal choice.  Try using them both and decide for yourself.

Just the previous line  of the documentation that is quoted, says the difference:

Modal dialogs prevent the user from interacting with anything other than the dialog. By contrast, modeless dialogs and sidebars let the user interact with the editor

The recommendation to use modal rather than modeless, assumes the UI focus should be on the dialog rather than the editor. For example, If the dialog asks a question, the user should answer it first rather than  ignoring it and using the underlying editor(say Google sheets).
On the other hand, if you're using the dialog to play a song or an video, while you also want to work with the underlying Google sheets, a modeless dialog is required. Notably, this scenario is rare. That's why a modal dialog is preferred in most cases.

Thank you for a clear explanation giving different scenarios, it makes sense now. I read that line in the documentation and I didn't understand it. I now get what is meant by "editor". I'm sure most people would just read that line in the documentation and understand immediately, but this is all new to me.

@TopMarx You're welcome. Glad to help.
